# PHP add html tag to first word

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

Trying to add HTML tags around the first word in each new line in WooCommerce short description and validate that the file exist. If it exist it will output a link.

I tried this:

```
$string = $short_description;
$keys = array('a1', 'a2', 'a3');
$patterns = array();
foreach($keys as $key)
    $patterns[] = '/\b('.$key.')\b/i';

echo preg_replace($patterns, '<a href="https://www.example.com/media/'.$product->get_sku().'/'.$product->get_sku().'$0.pdf">$0</a>', $string);

$url = preg_replace($patterns,  'https://www.example.com/media/' .$product->get_sku(). '/' .$product->get_sku(). '$0.pdf', $string); 

$handle = @fopen($url,'r'); 
if($handle !== false){ ?>
<?php echo preg_replace($patterns, '<li><a href="https://www.example.com/media/'.$product->get_sku().'/'.$product->get_sku().'$0.pdf">$0</a></li>', $string);?>
<?php } else {?>
<?php echo preg_replace($patterns, '<li>$0</li>', $string);?>
```

This is as close I could get, the limitation is that you need to add all words that needs to be changed (will be total 200+) and also the validation $url is not working as it echos the $string aswell.

So how can I either get the $url correct or is there a better way to wrap html tags to the first word on each new line?

Comment: Couldn't you read the file line by line then just push the tag at the beginning and end of each line?

Comment: @KevinGales Yes that worked better, went with `$rows = explode( "\n", $s );
foreach( $rows as $r ){
    echo preg_replace('/^([^ ]*)/', '<a href="media/'.$product->get_sku().'$1.pdf">$1</a>', $r);
    }` Still need to find a way to validate if file opens and remove the href tag if not, not sure if that can be done when getting URL with preg_replace?

Comment: Check out the functions ...file_exists() and is_readable() use one of those in a condition

Comment: @KevinGales Thank you very much, got it working. Still think I did this the wrong way around but at least it's running now. The input is: a1 title\n a2 titel\n etc, and the output I want is <a href="a1.pdf">a1</a> title, if the file exists, otherwise just output a1 title etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with:

```
$s = strip_tags($short_description, '<br>');
$rows = explode( "\n", $s );
foreach( $rows as $r ){
echo preg_replace('/^([^ ]*)/', '$1', $r);
}
```

and then with

```
if is_readable
```

to output link or not